# Hello world flask app stops working when customizing host to "0.0.0.0"

Tags: python, flask, ip-address, local, host

If you initialize the default PyCharm Flask starter project, or just follow the first section that starts up ["hello world"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) or just this:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

you'll have the same code as me. And it works fine, until I change the `host` argument to `0.0.0.0`, and then the application starts up like this:

```sh
$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And then when I go to that link, I get an invalid address error:

[image]

I need to use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` because that's the IP address AWS uses for open connections.

How can I even start to get the `0.0.0.0` address to work locally?

I'm working on **Windows**.

Comment: What do you mean by "change to 0.0.0.0"? It *already is* 0.0.0.0.

Comment: What if you use `0.0.0.0` in the code but `127.0.0.1` in the browser?

Comment: i forgot to remove the host kwarg, that was something **I** changed @mkrieger1

Comment: So if you use `run()` it works? Then why don't you leave it that way?

Comment: I literally explained in the question.. AWS inbounds on 0.0.0.0 and that's what this guy did https://github.com/denysthegitmenace/denys-on-data/blob/master/AWS%20Fargate%20-%20Flask%20App/app.py

Comment: but yes for some reason still going to 127.0.0.1 worked

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: windows @HenryHarutyunyan

Comment: @ark0n sorry can help :)

Comment: *"I need to use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 because that's the port AWS uses for open connections"* - 0.0.0.0 surely is not a port.

Comment: @Mat, `0.0.0.0` is a perfect VALID IP address even for a client. When you bind to it, it simply means _listen on all IP addresses configured on the host_

Comment: 0.0.0.0 tells it to bind to all available interfaces ... you still need to access it by a real ip address (127.0.0.1 if running locally or more likely the "public ip" in the aws console for ec2)

Comment: @Mat `0.0.0.0` works for me on Linux to connect with local server

Comment: @JoranBeasley, no hackery or witchcraft of any kind. It just works out of box. My guess on the question here is a firewall denying the connections or some kind of Windows policy in place and not an IP address problem. Maybe a proxy configured to allow `127.0.0.0/8` but not `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @Mat, the description on Wikipedia just say it is non-routable address but routing doesn't apply here since OP is running and testing on the same machine.

Comment: @accdias that is os specific and does not apply to windows

Comment: can you answer ill give you credit @accdias

Comment: or @JoranBeasley

Comment: @JoranBeasley, just tested on Windows, Linux, MacOS, and an old OpenBSD box I have here. All them simply worked. No hackery of any kind. Just run the script, open the browse ON THE SAME machine as the Flask app is running, and it will work.

Comment: @ark0n, I guess JoranBeasley is the one who deserves the credit. I just followed up him.

Comment: As one last comment, even http://0:5000 will work on the browser if it is opened **on the same machine** where the Flask app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess on the question here is a firewall denying the connections or some kind of Windows policy in place and not an IP address problem. Maybe a proxy configured to allow `127.0.0.0/8` but not `0.0.0.0`.

`0.0.0.0` is a perfectly **valid** IP address even for a client. When you bind to it, it simply means listen on all IP addresses configured on the host.

If you are running the browser **on the same** machine as you are running the Flask app, you can even simply point it to `http://0:5000` and it will show the content.

If you are running the application on AWS and are trying to access from a remote machine, than you need to specify the **public** IP address of your AWS instance instead, since `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable IP address (as any of the reserved private space IP addresses like `10.0.0.0/8`, `127.0.0.0/8`, `192.168.0.0/16`, and `172.16.0.0/12`).

Answer (score 2):

0.0.0.0 mean all IPv4 address , so it's incorrect to use it as a destination or a host address it's generally used to specify all ip  source ip addresses for I coming address ,

So should either give 127.0.0.1 or your machine ip adddress
[Link]https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735